# Why does this program work in Python 2.7.6 but not in Python 3?

Tags: python

I'm doing the problem described [here](https://www.codewars.com/kata/a-rule-of-divisibility-by-7/train/python):

I understand the code has this error in python 3:

```
File "main.py", line 3, in <module>
    Test.assert_equals(seven (1603), (7, 2))
  File "/home/codewarrior/solution.py", line 7, in seven
    newM = int(s[:(len(s)-1)]);
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '-'
```

Where/Why is their a difference in evaluation?

```
def seven(m):
    count=0;
    while(m/100 != 0):
        s = str(m);
        lastdigit = int(s[len(s)-1]);
        if(len(s)>1):
            newM = int(s[:(len(s)-1)]);
        count+=1;
        m = newM - 2*lastdigit;

    return (m,count);
```

Comment: check `m`. A division probably made that a float when it was an integer in python 2

Comment: Well for starters `7/2` is `3` in 2.7 (integer division) and `3.5` in 3 (float division)

Comment: [mcve] please !

Comment: `while(m/100 != 0):` should be `while(m//100 != 0):` to be faithful to python 2 integer division

Comment: a bit far fetched duplicate if you ask me... OP could avoid to divide in the first place

Comment: BTW, that code looks a bit unpythonic, with all those unnecessary semicolons. It also has 2 sets of redundant parentheses.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Fair points. And that's why I didn't hammer it straight away. I closed it because I don't think we need more than 2 answers here. But feel free to reopen it if you disagree.

Comment: @PM2Ring not going to reopen, no. question isn't good enough for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this has different behaviour in python 2 or 3

```
while(m/100 != 0):
```

In python 2, if `m < 100` the result is 0 and the loop stops.

In python 3, it doesn't.

Quickfix is to always use integer division

```
while m//100 != 0:  # or just: while m//100:
```

this will work the same (and properly as you expect) on any python version

At this point you could save a division and test absolute value of `m` instead of dividing and dropping the result:

```
while abs(m) >= 100:
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the while loop does not have the same stop condition.
In Python2 `m/100` returns the truncated result as an integer, while in Python3 it returns the exact result as a float